# Connecting to arduino bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have a project which I have to connect circuit's bluetooth. First I have to connect HC-06 module then send datas like "red", "green" and "blue". I have already coded circuit and it works with windows (C#) application but I want to make android application.

In summary, user select a color on android device. Android device will send that color's name to HC-06 module and circuit will run the right color motor.

I have tried different ways to make that successfully but android application shutted down. My last code is here:

```
BluetoothAdapter bt;

OutputStream outputStream;
BluetoothSocket soket;
StringBuilder sb;


private static final UUID uuid_kodu = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private static String mac_adres = "00:15:FF:F2:19:5F";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anasayfa);



    bt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    bt_control();

 }

private void bt_control() {

    if(bt==null) {
        Toast.makeText(Anasayfa.this, "Bt doesnt supports on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (!bt.isEnabled()) {

            Toast.makeText(Anasayfa.this, "Bt is opening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);


        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: "but android application shutted down" is not a good description of what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really simple library to connect your Android to the HC-06 module:

**https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Library**

To install it, add to your gradle app dependencies:

`compile 'me.aflak.libraries:bluetooth:1.2.4'`

This is a short sample:

```
Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth(this);
bluetooth.enableBluetooth();

bluetooth.setCommunicationCallback(new Bluetooth.CommunicationCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onConnect(BluetoothDevice device) {
              // device connected
              bluetooth.send("message");
      }

      @Override
      public void onDisconnect(BluetoothDevice device, String message) {
            // device disconnected
      }

      @Override
      public void onMessage(String message) {
            // message received (it has to end with a \n to be received)
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(String message) {
            // error occurred 
      }

      @Override
      public void onConnectError(BluetoothDevice device, String message) {
            // error during connection
      }
});

// three options
bluetooth.connectToName("name");
bluetooth.connectToAddress("address");
bluetooth.connectToDevice(device);
```

Comment: Just edited my anwser!

Comment: Thanks but I cant write 'Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth();' on onCreate

Comment: Did you add the dependencies?

Comment: Yes I did. I can write but there is a error in 'Bluetooth bluetooth = new bluetooth();' brackets. Error is 'Bluetooth (activity) in Bluetooth cannot be applied to ()' How can I solve that?

Comment: Oh yes right sorry: new Bluetooth(this)

Comment: Could you mark the answer as accepted (if you think it was the good one) ?

Comment: Yes, I've done it. But when I initalize libraries I have a problem with R. Cannot resolve sumbol R :/

Comment: It usually comes from your XML files

Comment: I check repearedly XML but there is not a problem. How can I find and solve ?

Comment: Try to clean the project and if the error persist, post some code of your gradle and xml files

Comment: I'm planning to do this too. But does it necessary to include UUID and MAC address of your HC-06 in the code? Or will your code discover this for me?

Comment: I did what you said but when I add your library into gradle, I always see 'Cannot resolve symbol R' error. I am searching that how to fix it for days but I cant. I tried to creating new project but it doesnt run with library. Is there any way?

Comment: Do you have any other log error message ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :/

Comment: Any way to fix it?